# reverse portrait not working in android

Tags: android, android-orientation

As the title says when calling

`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);`

or declaring in the manifest

```
android:screenOrientation="reversePortrait"
```

Doesn't rotate the screen at all. When I try to use reverse landscape it works fine. This doesn't make nay sense. Did I do something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I encountered this problem today, to make it work, either auto-rotate needs to be on or currently in landscape mode.

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you so much for your comment Sam. You are a god amongst men!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0);// turn off rotation according to accelerometer
        Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.USER_ROTATION, Surface.ROTATION_180);//reverse portrait
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.USER_ROTATION, Surface.ROTATION_0);//portrait
        Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 1);//turn on rotation according to accelerometer
    }
}
```

Do not forget adding permission to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Comment: Good. it works. But why android:screenOrientation="reversePortrait" not work at the first place?